# getting errors while configuring android on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, linux, open-source, ubuntu-11.10

I am following all steps using this [link](http://source.android.com/source/building.html).

The build was successful but when I say `make -j4` I get the following error:

```
  frameworks/base/libs/utils/RefBase.cpp: In member function ‘void android::RefBase::weakref_type::trackMe(bool, bool)’:
  frameworks/base/libs/utils/RefBase.cpp:483:67: error: passing ‘const android::RefBase::weakref_impl’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘voidandroid::RefBase::weakref_impl::trackMe(bool, bool)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/RefBase.o] Error 1
  make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp: In member function ‘void android::ResTable::print(bool) const’:
  frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp:4369:84: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp:4375:43: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp: At global scope:
  frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp:4429:1: fatal error: opening dependency file out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/ResourceTypes.d:   Permission denied
 compilation terminated.
  make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/ResourceTypes.o] Error 1
```

Why am getting this error?? Is there anything I've done wrong?? Thanks for any help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7671/discussion-between-padma-kumar-and-krishna-bhargavi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is:

```
out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/ResourceTypes.d: Permission denied
```

Make sure the permissions on that file are correct for the user that is running the command.

Comment: how to check the permissions?